# Keras, data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'> " in Batch Training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to batch-train my model as my dataset is quite large. However when calling

```
autoencoder_train = autoencoder.fit(my_training_batch_generator, 
                                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                                    verbose=1, 
                                    validation_data=my_testing_batch_generator,
                                    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    962         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle "
    963         "input: {}, {}".format(
--> 964             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
    965   elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    966     raise RuntimeError(

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'function'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

The functions `my_training_batch_generator` and `my_testing_batch_generator` are defined identically as:

```
def my_training_batch_generator(Train_df,batch_size,
                    steps):
    idx=1
    while True: 
        yield load_train_data(Train_df,idx-1,batch_size)## Yields data
        
        if idx<steps:
            idx+=1
        else:
            idx=1


dataDir = "/..."
def load_train_data(Train_df,idx,
              batch_size):
  i = 1
  x = np.zeros([batch_size, 100, 100, 100, 3])
  for n in range(idx*batch_size, idx*batch_size + batch_size):
    data = loadmat( Train_df+'volume'+str(n))  
    x[i] = np.array(data['tensor'])
    i = i + 1
  return (np.asarray(x),np.asarray(x))
```

so I am quite sure that the `generator` function passes numpy arrays to the autoencoder, hence I don't understand why the data adaptor can't handle input? I am new to batch training and the tutorial I followed ([here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/train-keras-model-with-large-dataset-batch-training-6b3099fdf366)) was meant for a classification task, while here I am using it on image to image regression via autoencoder. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were two:

1. Most importantly, I forgot to define the generator object before defining the model as follows:

```
my_training_batch_generator = batch_generator(Train_df, 256, steps_per_epoch)
my_testing_batch_generator = batch_generator(Test_df, 256, validation_steps)
```

Reason for which 2) I found myself with two generator and load functions (one for training and one for testing) and why I got the error 'impossible to handle the class "function"': I was passing a function to the autoencoder rather than a generator object.

Answer (score 2):

i can't reproduce the problem so i will share what i do for generator training.

First thing, i suggest you to try and print the output of the generator outside the training loop. Check that the shape matches the input to your model.

Second thing you are passing a function object to the fit method. I don't know if that syntax will ever work (and in fact keras complains about the "fucntion" type.

Hoping that this could be useful i will share what does work for me (batch size of 1) (tf 2.0)

```
def generate_data():
i = -1
while True:
    i += 1  
    if i == len(x_train): i = 0
        
    #print(x_train[i], y_train[i])
    #print(x_train[i].shape, y_train[i].shape)
    
    yield x_train[i], y_train[i]

 
def generate_val():

i = -1
while True:
    i += 1  
    if i == len(x_test): i = 0
    #print(x_test[i], y_test[i])
    #print(x_test[i].shape, y_test[i].shape)
    
    yield x_test[i], y_test[i]


#....model definition and so on ...

history = model.fit(generate_data(), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train), epochs=100, 
callbacks = [callback],class_weight={0:4, 1:1}, 
validation_data=generate_val(), validation_steps=len(x_test))
```

Comment: You may also try to call

autoencoder.fit(my_training_batch_generator(train_df, bla, bla), .... ) 

Passing the required arguments to the function however i do not see where you need Train_df explicitly...

Comment: I cannot print the type of the output of the generator as the code interrupts before it can compile and run. What is x_test in your code? It seems to me that you have the actual array already stored in the memory, is that right? I need batch training to actually load the data singularly

Comment: Hi, yes i have the full dataset loaded in memory but that should not matter. If you can't use the generator stand-alone then why should it work in the fit procedure?
As i understand you have a load_train_data function that returns values as red from a file with an index n. That should work as a stand-alone function. Is it the case?